# PHP-like array in C# webservice

Tags: java, c#, php, arrays, web-services

I have a webservice written in PHP and a client written in Java which work together. But now, I have to replace the PHP-webservice by a C#-webservice and I can't change the Java-Client. I already got a solution, that works, apart from one last step. One of the response-parameters has to be an array.
In PHP the response was:

```
<elements SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="ns1:stringArray">
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</item>
    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">XYZ</item>
</elements>
```

If there is only one element in the array, the response from C# looks like this and works:

```
<elements>ABC</elements>
```

But if there are more elements in the array, the response looks like:

```
<elements>
    <string>ABC</string>
    <string>XYZ</string>
</elements>
```

And the client throws an error.

Is there a way, to create an array in C#, which behaves like an array in PHP?

---

The C#-code is:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
public string[] elements {
    get {
        publicationsField = new string[] { "ABC", "XYZ" };
        return publicationsField;
    }
    set {
        this.publicationsField = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your C# code and someone will probably be able to tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could attempt to parse the response as XML and check if `<string>` is set.

If it is, you'd parse all of them in a loop and add them to an array. Otherwise, you'd create an array with one element, that element being the value of `<elements>`.

(Edit: Here's some pseudo-code as per OP's request for an idea on how to do this.)

```
xml = ParseXML(GetXML())
elements = xml[elements]

for each element in elements
    if sub element named string exists
        // it exists
    else
        // nope
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check if string is set"?

Comment: You can check if the `<string>` element is set in your XML as it's only there if there's multiple items.

Comment: I logged the response with TCPMon and it looks like the third code-example, I posted. So <string> isn't empty, but the Java-client says: "SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize." Now I'm searching for a way, to tell it, that <string>s are parts of an array and not children.

Comment: You can simply search `<elements>` using some form of text search function for the string `<string>`.

Comment: Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how it'd go in C# but I added some pseudo-code to my answer. Hope that helps!